# Include java utility classes to an "Enterprise Application Project" using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jar, ear, jboss7.x

I'm new to JavaEE. I have a Java Enterprise Application and I have a directory named framework which contains certain utility classes that should be shared among all modules of the resulting EAR.

Including them in the Java Enterprise Application should be easy as it theoretically requires only compiling the classes and packing them into a JAR file which in turn will be placed into EAR. This can be accomplished with ANT.

However, the question is, how can I in Eclipse create a Java Project containing these classes and add it to the Enterprise Application Project? When I create a new "Java Project" there is no such option as "Add Project to an EAR". How is it done then? Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check question: you have downloaded the [Eclipse for Java EE](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/jee.php), right?

An EAR project, in its properties (Alt+Enter or rt click on the project) has a section called "Deployment Assembly". There you can have your projects to the EAR.